# How to have a background image scale vertically in a responsive web page

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Html

```
<div id="header">
 <h1>Mark Osullivan</h1>
 <h2>Wedding Photography</h2>
</div>
```

Css

```
#header {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 max-width: 1024px;
 max-height: 191px;
 background-image: url(../images/Header.jpeg);
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;  
}  

#header h1 {
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-shadow: 3px 3px #000000;
 font-size: 50px;
}

#header h2 {
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-shadow: 3px 3px #000000;
 font-size: 35px;
}

#header h1, #header h2{
 text-align:center;
}
```

My background image currently scales horizontally when I change my screen size, however I would like to have it scale vertically as-well without setting media queries.

any help would be great, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have to maintain aspect ratio?

If yes, then set background as

```
#header {
  background: url(../images/Header.jpeg) center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

This will maintain the aspect ratio, it will scale the image both vertically and horizontally, although it will crop the image if viewport dimensions don't match the background image dimensions

Comment: Thank you for the reply, however when I move onto a smaller screen size parts of the image disappear, as in I would still like to be able to view the entire image just at a smaller ratio

Comment: All the parts of the background will be visible only if the aspect ratio of both the background and screen are equal, if not then the background will be cropped